# OVA or OVF images of ROS for VMware

Tags: ros, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

Trying to get started with ROS, but not always having my development hardware with me, I thought of using a virtual machine.

Turns out I found at least two option of Ubuntu and some other distro with ROS already installed. Great, right ?

In theory they are Open Virutal Format, BUT, trying to deploy them simply does not work. It seems that the schema reading the internal XML file cannot find the expected information.

I've tried this with ESXI 4.0, 4.1 and 5.5, with pretty much the same result, and I am assuming those images must run only under QEMU or similar.

Does anyone know of a VMware-compatible image I could use ?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172939/ova-or-ovf-images-of-ros-for-vmware/) by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2014-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of a published VMWare image.

You can always install a plain Ubuntu image in a VM and follow the ROS installation instructions for Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on 2014-06-19**:
Yep, true. The problem with that is that you never know, in the beginning, if you have installed all that is necessary, or if it is working. In fact, I've done that, with 12.04, and will try my luck with 14 as well. My goal is to make an image. Do we have any structure to publish it ?